# How to order titles with non-english characters?

Tags: channel-entries

I display a list of entries using

```
orderby="title"
sort="asc"
```

But titles starting with the Swedish character "Å" and "Ä" is sorted before "A" - and it should be last in the list. Like this:

... X Y Z Å Ä Ö

Is there a way (hack?) to solve this?

Regards, Magnus

Answer (score 3):

Risking tooting my own horn here, but [Low Alphabet](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-alphabet) will let you generate alphabetical lists and will ignore diacritics. If you don't want to use an add-on, you probably need to resort to PHP in your template.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience (working with Norwegian characters) you need to set the MySQL collation to "utf8_danish_ci". Admittedly counter-intuitive when working with Swedish content, but if it works...

Comment: Thanks. Strange, but I will try this.

Comment: That worked, @Svale! I changed the collation to utf8_swedish_ci and also created a new database with the default collation set to swedish. But, I also changed in database.php (in config) to: $db['expressionengine']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_swedish_ci';